# What is the point of using Android Binder class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, android-service-binding

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) says:

> If your service is used only by the local application and does not need to work across processes, then you can implement your own Binder class that provides your client direct access to public methods in the service.

But given the service is running in the same process as a client, it is possible to exchange data using any thread-safe structure like ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Binder class usage there is no meaning in possible messaging or data exchanging solution, but in the Android architecture in common that provides higher usabilty and security level that could be guaranteed without it:

> The most important improvement from Android application programmer’s
>   view is that methods on remote objects can be called as if they where local
>   object methods. This is achieved with a synchronous method call. Accordingly,
>   the calling client process is blocked for the duration of the answer of the server process. To its advantage, the client has no need to provide a threat method for
>   a asynchronous return message from the client.
>
> Another feature coming with intents is the intent filter. This is a declaration
>   for an service or app, which intents are forwarded by the system to this service or
>   app. But it does not guarantee security for all intents, because the intent filter
>   can be bypassed by explicit intents. In last consequence, the security relies
>   on checking of PID and UID like presented above.

For more details look here: [Android Binder. Android Interprocess Communication](https://www.nds.rub.de/media/attachments/files/2011/10/main.pdf)